# Excel "power of" function to JS

Tags: javascript

Any help converting Excel "power of" function to JavaScript?

Values are:

A1 = 99%
A2 = 45

formula is **= (A1^A2)*100**
results rounded to whole number is 64.

Answer (score 4):

The function `Math.pow(base, exponent)` might be what you are looking for.

You would do this:
`Math.pow(variable_for_A1, variable_for_A2) * 100`

Comment: if I go with 
Math.power(99^45)*100, I end up having 6.361854860638708e+91 as results, while I am expecting to get 64. Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: You should do Math.pow(0.99,45)*100, because 99% converted to decimal is 0.99, not 99.

Answer (score 2):

Power function in JavaScript can be written (at least) in 2 ways.

One is, as @iPhoenix described, another is,

```
a**b
```

```js
console.log(1.93**7.2)
console.log(2.0**6)
console.log(2**6.2)
console.log(7.9**43.2)
```